# Unable to upload a file using java

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

I am receving the following error:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext;)Ljava/util/List;`

The below is my code.

```
 InputStream inputstream = null;
 String gridDataStr ="";
 String errorMsg = "";       
 DTObject resultDTO = new DTObject();
 FileItem fileitem = null;
  //PrintWriter to send the JSON response back       
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    
// Check that we have a file upload request
  boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

  if (!isMultipart) {
      return;
  }

  // Create a factory for disk-based file items
  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

  // Sets the size threshold beyond which files are written directly to
  // disk.
  factory.setSizeThreshold(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE);

  // Sets the directory used to temporarily store files that are larger
  // than the configured size threshold. We use temporary directory for
  // java
  factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

  // constructs the folder where uploaded file will be stored
  String uploadFolder = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
          + File.separator + destinationDir;

  // Create a new file upload handler
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

  // Set overall request size constraint
  upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

    try{
        // Parse the request
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request); //error occurs here
        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                String filePath = uploadFolder + File.separator + fileName;
                File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);
                System.out.println(filePath);
                // saves the file to upload directory
                item.write(uploadedFile);
            }
        }

        // displays done.jsp page after upload finished
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/blahblah.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    }catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("Exception occured "+e);
       e.printStackTrace ();
       errorMsg="Error uploading file";
    }      
    System.out.println(">> In ExcelUpload::doPost()::Exit # errorMsg is - "+errorMsg);
    if(errorMsg!=null && errorMsg!=""){
        request.setAttribute("errorMsg", errorMsg);
    }
```

I am using `commons.fileupload1.2.2.jar`. Previously I was using `common.fileupload.1.2.1.jar` and there was the same error, so I changed the version still the error persists. Can anyone please spot the error?

Comment: You compiled against a different version from the one you are executing with. Use the same version.